# Java checking no of days in a month and adding dates that are missing

Tags: java

Hi I have the following arraylist strings of dates

["2010-08-01","2010-08-02","2010-08-04","2010-08-05","2010-08-06","2010-08-07","2010-08-08","2010-08-09","2010-08-11","2010-08-12","2010-08-13","2010-08-14","2010-08-15","2010-08-17","2010-08-18","2010-08-20","2010-08-21","2010-08-26","2010-08-28","2010-08-29"]

I have 2 aims that I want to achieve,

1) how to get the number of days for each month based on the year and month above?
2) how to add in the missing date(same format as above) for the entire sequence of dates strings above? For eg: 2010-08-01,2010-08-02,2010-08-04  -->I should add in 2010-08-03 in between 2010-08-02 and 2010-08-04

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to parse all the dates to find the maximum and minimum value.  Then generate a list of all the dates between the minimum and maximum.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    String[] dates = { "2010-08-01","2010-09-02","2010-07-28","2010-08-29" };
    String[] dates2 = fillInDates(dates, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dates2));
}

private static final long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24L * 3600 * 1000;

private static String[] fillInDates(String[] dates, String format) throws ParseException {
    if (dates == null || dates.length < 1) return dates;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE, max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String date : dates) {
        long time = sdf.parse(date).getTime();
        if(min > time) min = time;
        if(max < time) max = time;
    }
    String[] dates2 = new String[(int) ((max - min)/MILLIS_PER_DAY+1)];
    for(int i=0;i<dates2.length;i++)
        dates2[i] = sdf.format(new Date(min + i * MILLIS_PER_DAY));
    return dates2;
}
```

prints

[2010-07-28, 2010-07-29, 2010-07-30, 2010-07-31, 2010-08-01, 2010-08-02, 2010-08-03, 2010-08-04, 2010-08-05, 2010-08-06, 2010-08-07, 2010-08-08, 2010-08-09, 2010-08-10, 2010-08-11, 2010-08-12, 2010-08-13, 2010-08-14, 2010-08-15, 2010-08-16, 2010-08-17, 2010-08-18, 2010-08-19, 2010-08-20, 2010-08-21, 2010-08-22, 2010-08-23, 2010-08-24, 2010-08-25, 2010-08-26, 2010-08-27, 2010-08-28, 2010-08-29, 2010-08-30, 2010-08-31, 2010-09-01, 2010-09-02]

Answer (score 1):

Glad to see you are using ISO 8601.  What is one of the biggest advantages of ISO 8601?  That's right: you can sort dates by sorting strings.

So in your case first sort your array (or make a copy and sort that).  String sorting will work.

Now start traversing your list.  For each item, it is trivial to pick out the year, month, and day.  Whenever you see a *new* year and month, record that as your minimum day of the month.  As you walk the array, you will see gaps that you can fill in.  When you transition from one year-month to another, you'll be able to record the maximum day for the month.

THere's a bit of bookkeeping there, and you can't really insert into the middle of an array easily, so if I were you I would generate your result into a fresh array object.

It will take a few lines of code but remember to take advantage of the way string sorting is date sorting in ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1):

For your first task:

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(
            "2010-08-01", "2010-08-02", "2010-08-04", "2010-08-05", "2010-08-06", "2010-08-07", "2010-08-08",
            "2010-08-09", "2010-08-11", "2010-08-12", "2010-08-13", "2010-08-14", "2010-08-15", "2010-08-17",
            "2010-08-18", "2010-08-20", "2010-08-21", "2010-08-26", "2010-08-28", "2010-08-29"
    );

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();


    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(strings.size());

    for (String string : strings) {
        dates.add(dateFormat.parse(string));
    }

    int[] countByMonth = new int[12];
    for (Date date : dates) {
        calendar.setTime(date);
        countByMonth[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]++;
    }
```